# CMake: recursive dependency on external library

Tags: cmake, linker-errors, libraries

In a project `second` I build a library

```
ADD_LIBRARY (second <sources>)
TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES (second ${first_LIBRARIES})
```

where `first` was found with `FIND_PACKAGE` and is an external package.

Now a project `third` that includes the library `second` via

```
FIND_PACKAGE (second)
INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES (${second_INCLUDE_DIRS})
ADD_EXECUTABLE (third third.cpp)
TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES (third ${second_LIBRARIES})
```

cannot find the definition of the symbols in `first`, 
<strike>although these were required to build `second` itself.</strike>
although it was specified they would be needed while building `second`.
Indeed `second_LIBRARIES` is "/path/to/libsecond.a" and contains no trace of "libfirst".
How do I solve this?

Comment: I hope this is not a duplicate, looked quite a while - every post I found seemed to be complicated by a number of issues that are not present in this case.

Comment: You can try `TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES (second PUBLIC first::first)`.

Comment: Sorry but this is not clear to me... I just have the variables `first_LIBRARIES` and `first_INCLUDES` set as a result of the `FIND_PACKAGE`.
CMake does not thus recognise `first::first`: should I import the library in some other way?

Comment: Tried `ADD_LIBRARY` with flag `IMPORTED`, but does not seem to work.

Comment: `... cannot find the symbols defined in first, although these were required to build second itself.` - for building **library** none symbol is needed to be *defined*. Check content of the `first_LIBRARIES` variable. If it is empty, then you use `find_package()` incorrectly. If it is not, then none of the library listed in this variable defines given symbol. In any case for futher debugging you need to provide more details (and code).

Comment: Indeed for building library `second` symbols need not be defined, but they are needed for building _executable_ `third`. The variable `first_LIBRARIES` seems correctly set to "/path/to/libfirst.a".
Note that, however, in the CMakeLists of `third`, only `second_LIBRARIES` is defined. I'm thinking of how I can be more concrete...

Comment: So it is `FindSecond.cmake` script which doesn't properly set libraries for link (variable *second_LIBRARIES*). The most direct way is to fix that script. As for workarounds... you may use `find_package(first)` (and variables it defines) when build executable.

Comment: So it is `FindSecond.cmake`'s responsibility to know the internal structure of `second` and specify appropriate libraries... Interesting. As for the workaround, I just came to the conclusion it wouldn't be so bad after all.
Thanks for your help!